# AuthenticationSuccessHandler in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I've used spring security in a Spring Boot application and there are 2 types of users: one is an ADMIN, and one just a simple user. I get the data from a `DataSource`, then I execute an SQL query.

My problem is with a **redirection**: for every user I have a different homepage. I'm trying to use to `AthenticationSuccessHandler`, but it won't work.

Please help.

---

My Spring security class configuration :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Securityhandler successHandler;

    // Pour l'authentification des Utilisateur de Table Utilisateur
    @Autowired  
    public void GlobalConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource) 
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT  \"Pseudo\" AS principal , \"Password\" AS  credentials , true FROM \"UTILISATEUR\" WHERE \"Pseudo\" =  ? ")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT  u.\"Pseudo\" AS principal , r.role as role  FROM \"UTILISATEUR\" u ,\"Role\" r where u.id_role=r.id_role AND \"Pseudo\" = ?  ")
            .rolePrefix("_ROLE");
    }

    // ne pas appliqué la securité sur les ressources 
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/bootstrap/**","/css/**");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()   
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()   
                .authenticated()        
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(successHandler);
    }

}
```

And this is my *AuthenticationSuccessHandler*:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

public class Securityhandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_Admin")) {
            response.sendRedirect("/admin/home.html");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error in the console:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Comment: And what is expected to create an instance of the `SecurityHandler`? There is no `@Component` nor is it declared as a `@Bean`. So on instance will ever exist.

Comment: could explain to me am really a newbie in spring security

Comment: That has nothing to do with Spring security, that is basic spring usage... You need to tell spring which objects to instantiate else it cannot autowire those instances.

Comment: how i don't get it is by @autowire in fornt of the  name of the class that want to inject it's methods

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Securityhandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

     public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException  {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            response.sendRedirect("admin/home.html");
        }
    }
}
```

You've missed the [`@Component`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) annotation in your success handler class.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than sublcassing `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, 
It's worth knowing about the Spring security role-checking config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
    ...
}
```

OR pre-checking a Role per endpoint:

```
@Autowired
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

}
```

where the default Role prefix is `ROLE_`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic