# Multiple Role SecurityConfiguration Spring MVC + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, security, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have 2 types of user roles, and i like to set a diferent page for every type of user after login, but i don't know how can make this.

SecurityConfiguration

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String SQL_LOGIN = "select username, password, active as enabled \n"
            + "from user where username = ?";

    public static final String SQL_PERMISSION = "select u.username, r.role as authority\r\n" + 
            "           from user u join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id join role r on ur.role_id = r.role_id\r\n" + 
            "           where u.username = ?";

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configurGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery(SQL_LOGIN)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(SQL_PERMISSION).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()); // bcrypt

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/vehicle/list", true)
        .and()
        .logout();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

WebMvcConfig

```
@Configuration
```

public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
}
```

How i can make to diferent endpoint page, one for ADMIN and other for User?

```
//(ADMIN)
.loginPage("/login").permitAll() 
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/vehicle/list_admin", true)


//USER
.loginPage("/login").permitAll() 
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/vehicle/list", true)
```

Something like that, someone can help-me please?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement an AuthenticationSuccessHandler that checks  the role and make a redirection based on the role.

Check the next answer to get an idea about how to implement the Handler.

[AuthenticationSuccessHandler Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286112/authenticationsuccesshandler-spring-security)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. Something like the code below should do the trick.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws
            IOException,
            ServletException {
        User principal = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        boolean isAdmin = false;
        Iterator<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityIterator = principal.getAuthorities().iterator();
        while (grantedAuthorityIterator.hasNext()) {
            if (grantedAuthorityIterator.next().getAuthority().equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")) {
                isAdmin = true;
            }
        }
        if (isAdmin) {
            response.sendRedirect("/vehicle/list_admin");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/vehicle/list");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in your Spring Security configuration file you will need to add this option. `.successHandler(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler)`.